# Adding a simple "$" dollars sign in Xcode label

Tags: xcode, label

I just want to add a dollar sign to my label.  That's it. But I don't want to use NSNumberFormatter.  This is possible right?

This code prints a user's score in the game:

```
[_score setText: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"score"]];
```

I tried this code to add a dollar sign:

```
_score.text = [@"$%@" stringByAppendingString:_score.text];
```

But it does not print the "$" dollar sign.  Any help?  Once again, I don't want to use NSNumberFormatter.

Comment: Are you trying prefix a '$' to the score?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement:

```
    _score.text = [@"$%@" stringByAppendingString:_score.text];
```

Tries to append the _score.text to @"$%@" 
What you should do is something like

```
_score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@", _score.text];
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
 NSString *score= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"score"];
    scoreLabel.text =[@"$" stringByAppendingString:score];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working code snippet:

```
[_score setText: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"score"]];
_score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@", _score.text];
_score.text = [_score.text stringByAppendingString:@",000"];
```

Thanks Everyone!